# How to compare 2 columns and return the difference in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

We have 2 columns in one table in oracle SQL as
Col1= "there is book on the table"
Col2= "there are flowers on the chair"
Now I need the result as differed data in the column3 as new column col3.
The col3 result should be
"are flowers chair".
How to achieve this in oracle SQL??

Comment: That is not a task you would usually solve in SQL. If you were interested in words, you would store the words in your database, not multi-word strings as you are doing. A programming language would be better suited for the task (e.g. PL/SQL). If you want to do this in SQL, you should use a recursive query to loop through the words.

Comment: What if the two strings are 'your mama wears army boots' and 'all I want for Christmas is my two front teeth'  ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option (which follows what you asked). Read comments within code.

```
SQL> with test (id, col1, col2) as
  2    (select 1, 'there is book on the table',
  3               'there are flowers on the chair'
  4     from dual
  5    ),
  6  -- split sentences into words (each in its own line)
  7  sent1 as
  8    (select id,
  9         column_value cv,
 10         regexp_substr(col1, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) word
 11     from test cross join
 12       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col1, ' ') + 1
 14                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15    ),
 16  sent2 as
 17    (select id,
 18         column_value cv,
 19         regexp_substr(col2, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) word
 20     from test cross join
 21       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 22                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col2, ' ') + 1
 23                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 24    )
 25  -- final result
 26  select a.id,
 27         listagg(b.word, ' ') within group (order by a.cv) result
 28  from sent2 b join sent1 a on a.id = b.id and a.cv = b.cv and a.word <> b.word
 29  group by a.id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ------------------------------
         1 are flowers chair

SQL>
```

Comment: This doesn't give the expected difference if you add a word [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0002642497d58bc39c1754ef4e688930). It also doesn't work with multiple rows; you would only need to add `GROUP BY a.id` at the end to fix that latter issue though.

Comment: Well, as I said, it follows what's being said in the question. As of ID ... gosh, I *dragged* it through all code and forgot to add to add it to final SELECT. Thank you, @MT0.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```sql
WITH words ( rid, col, name, id, word ) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         CASE INSTR(col, ' ')
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ' ') + 1)
         END,
         name,
         1,
         CASE INSTR(col, ' ')
         WHEN 0
         THEN col
         ELSE SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, ' ') - 1)
         END
  FROM   ( SELECT ROWID AS rid, col1, col2 FROM table_name )
  UNPIVOT ( col FOR name IN (col1, col2) )
UNION ALL
  SELECT rid,
         CASE INSTR(col, ' ')
         WHEN 0
         THEN NULL
         ELSE SUBSTR(col, INSTR(col, ' ') + 1)
         END,
         name,
         id + 1,
         CASE INSTR(col, ' ')
         WHEN 0
         THEN col
         ELSE SUBSTR(col, 1, INSTR(col, ' ') - 1)
         END
  FROM   words
  WHERE col IS NOT NULL
),
paired_words ( rid, id1, id2 ) AS (
  SELECT c1.rid,
         c1.id AS id1,
         c2.id AS id2
  FROM   ( SELECT rid, id, word FROM words WHERE name = 'COL1' ) c1
         INNER JOIN
         ( SELECT rid, id, word FROM words WHERE name = 'COL2' ) c2
         ON (c1.rid = c2.rid AND c1.word = c2.word)
),
max_path ( rid, path ) AS (
  SELECT rid,
         path
  FROM   (
    SELECT rid,
           SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(id2, ',') || ',' AS path,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY rid ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) AS rn
    FROM   paired_words
    CONNECT BY PRIOR rid = rid
    AND    PRIOR id1 < id1
    AND    PRIOR id2 < id2
  )
  WHERE  rn = 1
)
SELECT LISTAGG(word, ' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY id) AS missing
FROM   words w
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   max_path mp
         WHERE  w.rid = mp.rid
         AND    mp.path LIKE '%,' || w.id || ',%'
       )
AND    w.name = 'COL2'
GROUP BY rid;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( col1, col2 ) AS
SELECT 'there is book on the table', 'there are flowers on the chair' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'there is book on the table', 'there is a book on the table' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'there is book on the table', 'there is book there is book on the table on the table' FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | MISSING |
> | --- |
> | are flowers chair |
> | a |
> | there is book on the table |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c95d5f131680c604c6f6d694880d0f06)*

Comment: Thanks @MT0 for quick response... Here we need the difference with respect to the order also...for example Col1 as 'Thomas Alva Edison' and Col2 as 'Alva Thomas Edison scientist' the expected result is 'Alva Thomas scientist'...but from your suggested query the result was 'Thomas scientist'....how to achieve this?? Sorry if I create any confusion in explaining my question